# Manually animate ASDisplayNode Texture (AsyncDisplayKit)

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation, asyncdisplaykit

I've been trying to animate ASDisplayNode for a while now, without any real progress.
I've read and try lots of examples, including the Texture transition API https://texturegroup.org/docs/layout-transition-api.html.
I would like to use a callback animation frame so I can coordinate the property change of some elements over time. 
While using with UIKit I've been using https://github.com/timdonnelly/Advance which has a very simple API that hooks to DisplayLink and provide simple callbacks on value change overtime.
At the very least I would like a very simple animation of height to work:

`UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.height = 500
})`

And it doesn't.
Furthermore, I would even prefer a callback animation where I get a callback (overtime) whenever displaying is ideal (similar to Displaylink).

Thanks!